# Pass Selected Drop Down List Value to Controller Action and then Populate Another Drop Down List Based on Value

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to select a manufacturer from a list and then based on what manufacturer the user selects, populate a list of models.

**View:**

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Manufacturer.ManufacturerName, "Model",
            htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.DropDownList("ManufacturerID", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Manufacturers,
                htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Manufacturer.ManufacturerName, "",
                new { @class = "text-danger", onchange = "PopulateModels()" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model.ModelName, "Model",
            htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.DropDownList("ModelID", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Models,
                htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Model.ModelName, "",
                new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
         function PopulateModels()
         {
              var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("GetModelList", "FaultController", new { manufacturer="ManufacturerID" }))';
              window.location = url;
         }
    </script>
```

**Controller:**

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetModelList(Manufacturer manufacturer)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> modelList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        var models = db.Models.Where(m => m.ManufacturerID == manufacturer.ManufacturerID);

        foreach (Model model in models)
        {
            modelList.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = model.ModelName,
                Value = model.ModelID.ToString()
            });
        }

        var sortedModelList = (from model in modelList
                               orderby model.Text
                               select model).ToList();

        return sortedModelList;
    }

public ActionResult Create(...)
    {
        .
        .
        .

        ViewBag.Models = new List<SelectListItem>();
        ViewBag.Manufacturers = GetManufacturerList();
    }
```

As you can see, the ViewBag for Models is initially empty, when a manufacturer is selected I want this ViewBag to be updated with all of the models that hold that manufacturer.

I feel like I'm close but cannot figure out what to next, a point in the right direction would be great. I'm also not sure if what I have done so far is completely correct, so if anyone can spot anything I've overlooked or any suggestions on how to improve my code would also be appreciated.

I hope this makes sense, any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

**Updated Code:**

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Manufacturer.ManufacturerName, "Model",
            htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.DropDownList("ManufacturerID", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Manufacturers,
                htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" , @id= "Manufacturers" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Manufacturer.ManufacturerName, "",
                new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model.ModelName, "Model",
            htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.DropDownList("ModelID", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Models,
                htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" , @id = "Models"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Model.ModelName, "",
                new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function(){
          $("#Manufacturers").change(function(){
             var v= $(this).val();
             $("#Models").empty();
             $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetModels","Fault")?id="+v,function(data){
                 $.each(data,function(a,b){
                   $("#Models").append('<option value="'+b.Value+'">'+b.Text+'</option>');
                 });
             });
          });

        });
    </script>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetModels(int id)
    {
        var models = db.Models.Where(m => m.ManufacturerID == id)
                       .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                       {
                           Value = x.ModelID.ToString(),
                           Text = x.ModelName
                       }).ToList();
        return Json(models, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is making the browser to navigate to the other action method. But what you ideally need is to get this data using ajax and use that to build the SELECT options for the second dropdown.

So setup a change event handler for the first dropdiwn.

```
$(function(){
  $("#ManufacturerID").change(function(){
     var v= $(this).val();
     $("#Models").empty();
     $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetModels","YourControlleName")?id="+v,function(data){
         $.each(data,function(a,b){
           $("#Models").append('<option value="'+b.Value+'">'+b.Text+'</option>');
         });
     });
  }); 

});
```

Now you have a `GetModels` action method which accepts the manufacturer id in Id parameter and return the corresponding model.

```
public ActionResult GetModels(int id)
{
   var models = db.Models.Where(m => m.ManufacturerID == id)
                  .Select(x=>new SelectListItem { Value=x.Id.ToString(),
                                                  Text=x.Name}).ToList();
   return Json(models,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oi3EW4) is a working dotnetfiddle with dummy data for your reference.

Comment: I have tried this and when I change the manufacturer in the dropdown, the models are still blank. The developer console shows: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined, for the line: $(function(){.

Comment: Do you have any js errors ? (check browser console) Is it making the network call to GetModels (check browser console again!). Also make sure to remove the call to your old `PopulateModels` method.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally submitted the comment without the error (now added in above comment). I added a breakpoint in the 'GetModels' action method and it doesn't appear to stop here. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: what you mean " it doesn't appear to stop here" ? Did you check the browser network tab ? Is it making the asyn call ? What is the response coming back ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the code execution doesn't pause at my breakpoint in the GetModels method. I'm using Chrome, opened developer tools, then Network tab and I don't think I can see anything?

Comment: Are you saying when you change an option in your Manufacturer dropdown, you are not seeing a network call made to the GetModels in your browser's network tab ? It should as long as you don't have any script errors.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle - that is exactly what I am trying to do. I have been playing around for the past few hours but it simply won't work and I can't see any network call being made and only that one error I previously mentioned. I have updated my code to reflect this.